# jQuery selectors - find objects without specified attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have several objects on a page and I want to perform an operation using jQuery only on some of them - the ones that don't have a specified attribute. So:

```
<li style='...'>some text</li>
<li style='...'>some other text</li>
<li>some very diffrent text</li>
```

and in javascript I would have:

```
$('li[style]').hide();
```

that would hide all elements with a `style` sttribute. But if I want to hide the ones **without** it, how should my selector look like?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
jQuery("li:not([style])").hide();
```

Comment: Very simple, on one line... perfect answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the :not psuedo-selector to look up elements that *don't* match a certain selector. In your example, you want to select all li elements without the style attribute, so you'd use something like this:

```
$('li:not([style])').hide();
```

You can also combine this with other selectors:

```
$('#div input:not(:checked)').show();
```

It's a pretty powerful tool!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('li:not([style])').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find it clearer and more performant to use the [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method instead of the selector. As an example:

```js
$('li').not('[style]').hide();
```

This is also what the jQuery devs [recommend](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).