# jQuery - Find element with rel attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have two kind of elements

```
<i rel="tooltip" class='icon-ok'>
<i title="Teste" class='icon-info'>
```

The first one is a tooltip effect, the second a popover

What I'm trying to do is avoid rework so I don't need to create a script based on the class on every html I have.

I did this on my base html:

```
$('body').find('i').tooltip();
```

The problem is that it is adding the tooltip effect on the other `<i>` elements without the rel attribute.

I need to search for elements with the rel attribute and set the tooltip effect on them.

Thanks

**EDIT**

If I try to do the opposite of what was said on the correct answer, get the `<i>` elements without the rel attribute.
Found the solution here: [jQuery selectors - find objects without specified attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969141/jquery-selectors-find-objects-without-specified-attribute)

[vrutberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230654/vrutberg) - `jQuery("li:not([style])").hide();`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`$('i[rel]').tooltip();`

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: Or `$('body').find('i[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();` as well.

Comment: and is it possible to check in the popover situation, without the rel?

Answer (score 26):

the exact one

```
$('i[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

Comment: quotes help for spaces

Answer (score 2):

yon can select all elements with href att with this selector

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("[rel]")

});
```