# Use jQuery to select list items that *don't* contain a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to add a background color to all the elements of my ul that don't contain a link

HTML:

```
  <ul id="list">
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></li>
    <li>Not a link</li>
    <li><a href="http://live.com/">Live</a></li>
    <li>Not a link</li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
  $('#list li').css({'background': 'red'});
```

But that changes all of them - http://jsbin.com/pusogihuvi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all elements without child node in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061594/get-all-elements-without-child-node-in-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selectors - find objects without specified attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969141/jquery-selectors-find-objects-without-specified-attribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `:not` pseudo selector to exclude matches. Use a `:has` pseudo selector to see if an element contains a specified match (without losing the ancestor scope).

```
$('#list li:not(:has(a))').css({'background': 'red'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `:not` and `:has`:

```
$('#list > li:not(:has(a))').css({'background': 'red'});
```

http://jsbin.com/quyalunipo/1/edit?html,css,js,output